# How subtract two value in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, count, subtraction

I have 3 value which is AmountOfRent , AmountPaid and RemainingAmount .

how i can subtract the AmountOfRent and AmountPaid to get the value of RemainingAmount

AmountOfRent - AmountPaid = RemainingAmount

I do not,t know how i write the code in mvc .

```
<td>   
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contracts.AmountOfRent)
</td>

<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AmountPaid)
</td>

<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RemainingAmount)
</td>
```

Comment: Do you mean `(item.contracts.AmountOfRent -  item.AmountPaid)` ?

Comment: Calculate that value in controller?

Comment: (item.contracts.AmountOfRent - item.AmountPaid)  yes that wat i mean

Comment: how i can do that ? can write the code

Comment: At first learn how to code ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare in model to count RemainingAmount

```
public decimal AmountOfRent { get; set; }

public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }

public decimal RemainingAmount => AmountOfRent - AmountPaid;
```

Comment: so then i do not write any thing else ?

Comment: In case, 2 properties AmountOfRent and AmountPaid user can input, you need to add event in client to recalculate RemainingAmount.

Comment: how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume this is your controller's action method, which returns model to your view:

```
public ActionResult Something()
{
    //. . .
    var model = manager.GetModel();
    model.RemainingAmount = model.AmountOfRent - model.AmountPaid;
    return View(model);
}
```

or even you can have your property to return your desired result on get:

```
private int remainingAmount;

public int RemainingAmount
{
    get { return AmountOfRent - AmountPaid; }
    set { remainingAmount = value; } //this may not be needed
}
```

Comment: what mean by the manager ? because there are read line under this words

Comment: That's just an example, it means wherever you get your object or create it.

Comment: sorry i do not understand , can tell me what i must be  write ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform it in cshtml file then below is the soution:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contracts.AmountOfRent)
</td>

<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AmountPaid)
</td>

<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RemainingAmount)
</td>
<td>
@{
    var result= item.contracts.AmountOfRent - item.AmountPaid;
    Html.Display(result)
}
</td>
```

Comment: it is not coming

Comment: Attach a screenshot please of what is coming.